# Filtering 2D Array with a Variable Filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to break out an array into several different arrays to paste information across several sheets. I am having trouble filtering my main data array (bigArray) dynamically with a separate array (sheetCheck). If I type a static filter i.e. "02A" the filter works. How can I modify my filter to accept variable information?

```
function testArray (){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  //Get full array of Budget Pricing Breakdown Sheet
  var originalArray = ss.getRangeByName('XxTestRange').getValues();
  //Delete unused columns from array. Only Leaves sheetNumber, description, qty, UM, unitCost
  var newArray = originalArray.map(function(row){return[row[0],row[5],row[6],row[7],row[10]];});
  //Delete unused rows that have a value of X in the sheetNumber
  var bigArray = newArray.filter(function(item){return item[0] != "X";});

  //Get array of Applicable Tabs
  var originalSheetsArray = ss.getRangeByName('XxTestRange2').getValues();
  //Remove unused column
  var newSheetsArray = originalSheetsArray.map(function(row){return[row[0],row[2]];});
  //Delete not applicable rows
  var sheetCheckBad = newSheetsArray.filter(function(item){return item[1] != "Not Applicable"});
  //Separate just appicable trades
  var sheetCheck = sheetCheckBad.map(function(row){return[row[0]];});

  for (var i=0; i<sheetCheck.length;i++){
    var sheetNumber = sheetCheck[i];
    //Logger.log(sheetNumber)
    var pasteArray = bigArray.filter(function(item, sheetNumber){return item[0] == sheetNumber})
    //var pasteArray = bigArray.filter(filterSheetLogic)
    Logger.log(sheetNumber);
    Logger.log(pasteArray);
  }
}

//Pull individual Arrays based on sheet numbers
var filterSheetLogic = function(item, sheetNumber){
  if (item[0] == sheetNumber){
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: In order to correctly understand about your situation, can you provide the sample values for input and output you want?

Comment: I believe the OP is asking how to be able to include the variable sheetnumber as a function parameter `var pasteArray = bigArray.filter(function(item, sheetNumber){return item[0] == sheetNumber})`  because paste array is currently empty on all iterations. If one removes the variable sheetNumber the function works correctly. I just used 11 columns of numbers.

Comment: Here's a link to a sample spreadsheet. I am using the array filters to break the data from Budget Pricing Breakdown sheet into separate arrays that can be pasted into the other sheets titled 02A, 03A,..,04A. The full version of the sheet copied hundreds of rows from budget pricing breakdown and distributing them to over 100 sheets. [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fbZOudRYi_CajM0fJ4HQdrT53RRlBwbRn9Aa9v53mQQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @Cooper you are absolutely correct. Deleting the sheetNumber variable fixed my issues. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can't call that

```
 bigArray.filter(function(item, sheetNumber) ...
```

Because the callback of the filter get its own arguments. In this case `sheetNumber` always equals the array's index `0`, `1`, `2` etc.

My case is building a fabric to generate a valid callback. For an example

```
/**
 * The big array filter's builder. It's a fabric
 * @param {string} sheetNumber
 * @returns {object} The filter's callback
 */
var filterBuilder_ = function(sheetNumber) {
  return function(item, _, __) {
    return item[0] == sheetNumber;
  };
};
```

After this change your main loop to

```
for (var i = 0; i < sheetCheck.length; i++) {
  var sheetNumber = sheetCheck[i][0];
  var bigArrayfilter = filterBuilder_(sheetNumber);
  var pasteArray = bigArray.filter(bigArrayfilter);
  Logger.log(sheetNumber);
  Logger.log(pasteArray);
}
```

*I apologize if I do not understand the task correctly.*